# Drawing a rectangle with one side skewing based on degress/radians

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, actionscript, geometry

I'm trying to take one side of a rectangle and skew the side based on degree/angle.

[image]

Comment: How's your trig? That's a parallelogram, BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I whipped up some code for you
Any questions just ask.

```
import flash.geom.Matrix;

var temp_matrix = new Matrix();

var square:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(square);
square.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x000000);
square.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,100);
square.graphics.endFill();

var angle:Number = -10; // the angle of degrees
temp_matrix.b = Math.PI * 2 * angle / 360;// y skew
//temp_matrix.c = Math.PI * 2 * angle / 360;// x skew

var sourceMatrix:Matrix = square.transform.matrix;// get existing matrix
sourceMatrix.concat(temp_matrix); // apply skew to existing matrix
square.transform.matrix = temp_matrix;// assign the new skew

square.x = 100
square.y = 100
```

[SECOND ROUND]

```
var trapezium:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(trapezium);
trapezium.x = 100;
trapezium.y = 100;

var dir:Boolean = true;
var side:Boolean = true;
var angle:Number = 0; // the angle of degrees
var w:Number = 300;
var h:Number = 80;


var timer:Timer = new Timer(16);
timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, tick );
timer.start();

function tick(e:TimerEvent):void{
    var radians:Number = Math.PI/180*angle;
    trapezium.graphics.clear();
    trapezium.graphics.beginFill(0x000000)
    if( side){
        // long side is right side
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(w,0);
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(w,radians*w+h);
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(0,h);
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
    }else{
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(w,0);
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(w,h);
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(0,radians*w+h);
        trapezium.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
    }
    trapezium.graphics.endFill();
    if(angle>=10){
        dir = false;
    }
    if(angle<=0){
        dir = true;
    }
    if(dir){
        angle = angle+.2;
    }else{
        angle = angle-.2;
    }
    if( Math.floor(angle*10) <= 0 ){
        side = !side;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi this is a lot of help! Thanks so much. Unfortunately it must be my bed time because I was a bit unclear on what I originally wanted. I just edited the post so check it out.

Comment: Lol that is very different then your original picture you posted. For that you can't use the matrix you have to draw it. Lets see if i can come up with something.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to get one part down and try to figure out the rest. I'm going to mark you as correct anyways, since you had what was originally called for.

Comment: I created something that mimics your posted gif again lol. The code is sloppy but you will at least get the usage.

Answer (score 3):

Take the tangent of the angle and multiply by the width of the rectangle to get the delta y for the bottom axis so you would have

[x1,y1] as the origin of the rectangle (which never changes)

[x1+length, y1+deltaY] as the right bottom corner

Comment: +1. I just want to clarify that the width as used here is the final left-to-right width of shape, not the length of the bottom segment (which is, in fact, longer).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to try this now!

Comment: Hi this is a lot of help! Thanks so much. Unfortunately it must be my bed time because I was a bit unclear on what I originally wanted. I just edited the post so check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know AS, but after editing this looks like filled polygon with vertices:

```
P0 =(X0, Y0)
P1 = (X1, Y0)
if Angle >= 0 then
  P2 = (X1, Y1)
  P3 = (X0, Y1 + (X1-X0) * Tan(Angle))
else
  P2 = (X1, Y1 - (X1-X0) * Tan(Angle))
  P3 = (X0, Y1)
```